# Why JQuery .html() do not work on singel div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JQuery (2.1.1. + FF 33.1) .html() do not work on singel div-Tags?

```
 <head>
    <title>jquery Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").html( "hans" );

    alert( "hans2:" + $("#name2").html() + ":");

    $("#name2").html( "hans2" );

    $("#name3").html( "hans3" );

    $("#version").html( $().jquery );

 });

 </script>

 JQuery-Version: :<div id="version">??</div>:

 Name: :<div id="name">??</div>: <<< work

 Name: :<div id="name2"/>: <<< not work

 Name: :<div id="name3">??</div>:

 <br>
 End

 </body>
```

The result:

> JQuery-Version: :
>
> 2.1.1
>
> : Name: :
>
> hans
>
> : Name: :
>
> hans2

The statement:

```
 $("#name2").html( "hans2" );
```

substitute complete html until end of file!

Comment: Browsers usually accept self-closing DIVs, nevertheless they are not allowed according to the specification.

Comment: What is your doctype ?

Comment: Doctype is irrelevant in this matter. content-type isn't, but the question is tagged *html* and not *xhtml*

Comment: Agreed @Quentin, but Ops sometime do mistag. They are confused because they have seen something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jc362utj/

Comment: Which works because there is no element following the div. It has nothing to do with the doctype and nothing to do with the content-type.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks a lot. I was myself confused :( I never used self-closing tags myself on non-void elements, so I thought doctype could be relevant. Thank you. Good to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div id="name2"/>` is invalid HTML. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

You can only have a `/` at the end of a [start tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) if the element is a void element.

The end tag for a div is mandatory.

The div doesn't get closed until the end of the document so `$("#name2").html( "hans2" );` removes `Name: :<div id="name3">??</div>:<br> End` from the document before you try to put content into `#name3`.